# Unable to update a stock chart from a dynamically updated dropdown

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am building a stock price dashboard using dash, of the Nasdaq-100. The idea was to have two drop-down sections, the parent drop-down is used to parse the GICS sector from Nasdaq-100 and based on the selection on it, the children drop-down will have all the company related to the industry. Each new stock entered in the children drop-down will update the main stock chart.

I am fine with the dynamically update children drop-down section, but I am unable to update the graph. I am still new to this 'dashboard designing', can anybody help me figuring out the problem?

***Here is the full code:***

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import argparse
import yfinance as yf
import fundamentalanalysis as fa
from datetime import date as dt

def collect_sectors():
    src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasdaq-100"
    rawdf = pd.read_html(src)
    stock_list = rawdf[4]

    sectors = []
    for i in stock_list['GICS Sector']:
        if not(i in sectors):
            sectors.append(i)
    return sectors

def collect_stock_names(sector):
    src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasdaq-100"
    rawdf = pd.read_html(src)
    stock_list = rawdf[4]

    dstock_name = []
    for i in range(0, 101):
        if stock_list['GICS Sector'][i] == sector:
            dstock_name.append(stock_list['Company'][i])

    dtickers = []
    for i in range(0, 101):
        if stock_list['GICS Sector'][i] == sector:
            dtickers.append(stock_list['Ticker'][i])
    return dstock_name, dtickers

def collect_historical_data(ticker, startp=None, endp=None):
    dstock_history = yf.download(ticker, start=startp, end=endp)
    return dstock_history

def collect_fundamental_data(ticker, api):
    pass    #return a panda dataframe containing the info, or calculate directly here?

################ Dashnoard Layout #####################
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

sectors = collect_sectors()
api_key = ""

app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    children=[
        dash.html.Div(
            children=[
                dash.html.H1(children="Ratios Stock Analysis", className="header-title"),
                dash.html.P(
                    children='''
                        Fundamental analysis utility for ratio analysis.
                    ''', className="header-pargraph"
                ),
            ],
            className="header-block"
        ),
        dash.html.Div(
            children=[
                dash.dcc.Dropdown(options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in sectors], id="parent-dropdown", value=sectors[0]),
            ],
        ),
        dash.html.Div(
            children=[
                dash.dcc.Dropdown(id="children-dropdown", multi=True),
            ],
        ),
        dash.html.Div(
            children=[
                dash.dcc.DatePickerRange(id="date_range", 
                    min_date_allowed=dt(1970, 1, 1), 
                    max_date_allowed=dt(2023, 6, 8),
                    start_date=dt(2023, 5, 22), 
                    end_date=dt(2023, 6, 8)
                ),

            ],
        ),
        dash.html.Div(
            children=[
                dash.dcc.Graph(id='price-chart')
            ],
        ),
        #Financial Ratios right section
    ]
)
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("children-dropdown", "options"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("parent-dropdown", "value")
)
def update_dropdown(sector):
    stocks_name_list, tickers = collect_stock_names(sector)
    return [{'label': i, 'value': j} for i, j in zip(stocks_name_list, tickers)]

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("price-chart", "figure"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("children-dropdown", "value"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("date_range", "start_date"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("date_range", "end_date")
)
def upadte_chart(value, start_date, end_date):
    fig = go.Figure()
    price_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(column=len(value))
    
    for i in range(0, len(value)):
        price_data_frame[i] = collect_historical_data(value[i], startp=start_date, endp=end_date)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=price_data_frame[i]['Date'], y=price_data_frame[i]['Adj Close'], mode='lines', name=value))
    
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[start_date, end_date], title="{} Adjust Closed Price".format(','.join(value)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)